# How to create an allocator that uses a pre-allocated memory space?

Tags: c++, boost, allocator

I need to use a given memory region as a circular buffer. I am given a pointer and the size of the memory region that I am allowed to use, in my embedded system. I am thinking to use boost::circular_buffer class, but I need a custom allocator. I've never created allocator before. Could anyone point me to some example code of allocator that handles already-allocated memory?

Comment: This is a duplicate question of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927645/circular-buffer-with-pre-allocated-buffer?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular buffer with pre-allocated buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927645/circular-buffer-with-pre-allocated-buffer)