# Hinnant's short_alloc and alignment guarantees

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I have recently come across Howard Hinnant's [short_alloc](https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html) and this is the single best example of custom allocators I have seen.

But as I spent more time studying the code to integrate it in my personal project, it occurred to me that the `arena` class, providing the stack-based allocations, might not always return properly aligned memory. In fact, I fear that only the first allocation is guaranteed to be suitably aligned (as the buffer itself has a forced alignment), see below relevant code fragments:

```
template <std::size_t N>
class arena
{
  static const std::size_t alignment = 16;
  alignas(alignment) char buf_[N];
  char* ptr_;
  //...
};

template <std::size_t N>
char*
arena<N>::allocate(std::size_t n)
{
  assert(pointer_in_buffer(ptr_) && "short_alloc has outlived arena");
  if (buf_ + N - ptr_ >= n)
  {
    char* r = ptr_;
    ptr_ += n;
    return r;
  }
  return static_cast<char*>(::operator new(n));
}
```

I can think of a few ways to fix this (at the cost of some memory wastage), the easiest being to round the `size` in the `allocate/deallocate` function to a multiple of `alignment`.

But before changing anything, I would like to make sure that I am not missing something here...

Comment: Paging doctor [@HowardHinnant](http://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This code was written before I had `std::max_align_t` in my toolbox (which now lives in `<cstddef>`).  I would now write this as:

```
static const std::size_t alignment = alignof(std::max_align_t);
```

which on my system is exactly equivalent to the current code, but now more portable.  This is the alignment which `new` and `malloc` are guaranteed to return.  And once you have this "maximally aligned" buffer, you can put an array of any one type in it.  But you can't use the same `arena` for different types (at least not different types that have different alignment requirements).  And for that reason, perhaps it would be best to template `arena` on a second `size_t`, which is equal to the the `alignof(T)`.  In that way you can prevent the same `arena` from being accidentally used by types with differing alignment requirements:

```
arena<N, alignof(T)>& a_;
```

Assuming each allocation from `arena` has the same alignment requirements, and assuming the buffer is maximally aligned, then every allocation from the buffer will be suitably aligned for `T`.

E.g. on my system `alignof(std::max_align_t) == 16`.  A buffer with this alignment can hold arrays of:

- Types with `alignof == 1`.
- Types with `alignof == 2`.
- Types with `alignof == 4`.
- Types with `alignof == 8`.
- Types with `alignof == 16`.

As some environment may support types that have "super alignment" requirements, an added safety precaution would be to add (say within `short_alloc`):

```
static_assert(alignof(T) <= alignof(std::max_align_t), "");
```

If you are super paranoid you could also check that `alignof(T)` is a power of 2, though the C++ standard itself guarantees that this will always be true ([basic.align]/p4).

**Update**

I have taken a closer look at this problem and believe that rounding the requested allocation size up to the next `alignment` (as the OP suggested) is the best solution.  I have updated ["short_alloc"](http://howardhinnant.github.io/short_alloc.h) to do that on my website.

```
template <std::size_t N>
char*
arena<N>::allocate(std::size_t n)
{
    assert(pointer_in_buffer(ptr_) && "short_alloc has outlived arena");
    n = align_up(n);
    if (buf_ + N - ptr_ >= n)
    {
        char* r = ptr_;
        ptr_ += n;
        return r;
    }
    return static_cast<char*>(::operator new(n));
}
```

For special situations where you *know* that you don't need maximally aligned allocations (e.g. `vector<unsigned char>`), one can simply tweak `alignment` appropriately.  And one could also have `short_alloc::allocate` pass `alignof(T)` to `arena::allocate` and `assert(requested_align <= alignment)`

```
template <std::size_t N>
char*
arena<N>::allocate(std::size_t n, std::size_t requested_align)
{
    assert(requested_align <= alignment);
    assert(pointer_in_buffer(ptr_) && "short_alloc has outlived arena");
    n = align_up(n);
    if (buf_ + N - ptr_ >= n)
    {
        char* r = ptr_;
        ptr_ += n;
        return r;
    }
    return static_cast<char*>(::operator new(n));
}
```

This would give you confidence that if you adjusted `alignment` downward, you didn't adjust it too far downward.

**Update Again!**

I've updated the [description](https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html) and [code](https://howardhinnant.github.io/short_alloc.h) of this allocator quite a bit because of this excellent question (I had neglected this code for years).

The alignment check mentioned in the previous update is now done at compile-time (compile-time errors are always superior to run-time errors, even asserts).

Both the `arena` and `short_alloc` is now templated on alignment so that you can easily customize the alignment requirements you anticipate (and if you guess too low it is caught at compile-time).  This template parameter is defaulted to `alignof(std::max_align_t)`.

The `arena::allocate` function now looks like:

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t alignment>
template <std::size_t ReqAlign>
char*
arena<N, alignment>::allocate(std::size_t n)
{
    static_assert(ReqAlign <= alignment, "alignment is too small for this arena");
    assert(pointer_in_buffer(ptr_) && "short_alloc has outlived arena");
    auto const aligned_n = align_up(n);
    if (buf_ + N - ptr_ >= aligned_n)
    {
        char* r = ptr_;
        ptr_ += aligned_n;
        return r;
    }
    return static_cast<char*>(::operator new(n));
}
```

Thanks to *alias templates*, this allocator is easier to use than ever.  For example:

```
// Create a vector<T> template with a small buffer of 200 bytes.
//   Note for vector it is possible to reduce the alignment requirements
//   down to alignof(T) because vector doesn't allocate anything but T's.
//   And if we're wrong about that guess, it is a comple-time error, not
//   a run time error.
template <class T, std::size_t BufSize = 200>
using SmallVector = std::vector<T, short_alloc<T, BufSize, alignof(T)>>;

// Create the stack-based arena from which to allocate
SmallVector<int>::allocator_type::arena_type a;
// Create the vector which uses that arena.
SmallVector<int> v{a};
```

This isn't necessarily the final word in such allocators.  But hopefully this is a solid foundation upon which you can build your custom allocators.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. The problem I had observed was exactly that: "the same arena being accidentally used by types with differing alignment requirements".  So far I have "fixed" it by rounding up the size of [de]allocations to multiples of `max_align_t`.  I like your suggestion to add the alignment as a template parameter of `arena` better, but am not sure how this will work in combination with `short_alloc::rebind`.  i.e. won't there be cases where the underlying `arena` can no longer be shared by two related allocators? Anyway, I will give it a try. Thanks again.

Comment: @pragmatib: Your fix is better than mine.  I've adjusted my answer and updated my website.

Comment: cool, thanks for the updated code. In the `allocate` method, shouldn't you introduce a temporary variable to hold the aligned-up value? Without it, looks to me that the fall-back to `::operator new` might request a bit too much memory.

Comment: @pragmatib: That's not a bad suggestion, thanks.  And thanks to you I've also continued to update `short_alloc` over the past day to bring it up to what I consider modern standards.  My answer is already obsolete again (compared to my website).  The biggest change is that I'm now checking `requested_align <= alignment` at compile time.  I'm also trying to make it more convenient to request a reduced-alignment allocator/arena.  When I quit changing things I will update this answer again.

Comment: Wow, this is an awesome answer. I will need a bit more time to digest the details but it looks great. FWIW, I had been toying with another idea: support 2 two different alignments in a single `arena`. An "optimized" one, chosen upon first request, whose allocations would be reserved from the head of the buffer, and `max_align_t` for which the allocations would be reserved from the tail. I have not progressed much on the implementation, and I'm not sure that it's worth the added complexity compared to your new version. Thanks for all your feedback and expert advice - much appreciated.

Comment: @HowardHinnant please add license information to your code so it can be safely used. Most projects prohibit the use of unlicensed code, even open-source projects.

Comment: while using this with unordered_map on MSVC 2017 (C++14),memuse() prints the following:  memory = 0
alloc = 0
memory = 0
alloc = 0
memory = 24
alloc = 1
memory = 48
alloc = 2
memory = 48
alloc = 2
1 2 3 4

Comment: Crazy idea: can the templated implementation automatically pick the correct alignment (i.e. the minimum power-of-2 that will work), based on SFINAE and something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079196/sfinae-to-assert-that-code-does-not-compile ?  That is: try alignment=1, then if THIS_CODE_DOES_NOT_COMPILE(...some sample code that creates a container and inserts an item...), then try (via template recursion) alignment=alignment*2, etc.  with recursion base case set to aligment=alignof(std::max_align_t).

Comment: Suggestion for making the "this allocator is easier to use than ever" part even easier:
`template<typename WhatIHas> struct HasA { WhatIHas what_i_has; }; template<typename Container> struct ShortContainer : private HasA<typename Container::allocator_type::arena_type>, public Container { ShortContainer(): Container(this->what_i_has) {} }; template<typename T, size_t BufSizeBytes = 200> using ShortVector = ShortContainer<std::vector<T, short_alloc<T, BufSizeBytes, alignof(T)>>>;`  Then it can be used as simply `ShortVector<int> v;` or `ShortVector<int, 1000> v;`

Comment: Also, worth noting: when using std::vector with this allocator,
one should *always* call reserve(BufSizeBytes/sizeof(T)) immediately,
to avoid unexpected silent spillover to the heap.
This becomes apparent if we use a simpler variant of short_alloc that hard-errs
instead of spilling over to the heap.
The SmallVector type should perhaps do such a reserve() automatically in its ctor
(but unfortunately that might muddy the exposition of this answer a bit,
so maybe just call this out briefly at the end, instead).

Comment: One more suggestion for the SmallVector example:  when I see `SmallVector<int, 1000>`, I immediately think it's talking about 1000 ints; I (and perhaps others?) find it surprising that it's really talking about 1000/sizeof(int) ints.  Perhaps it would be less surprising if that template param was MaxItems rather than BufSizeBytes?