# SFINAE to assert() that code DOES NOT compile

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae

I feel certain it must be possible to use SFINAE (possibly with Macros) to static_assert() that arbitary code will *not* compile.

There are some complex cases in my code-base, where i have a class that I want to forbid taking temporaries (I believe the pattern is):

```
class(const class&& tmp)=delete; /* deny copying from an unnamed temporary */
class (class&& rhs){/* allow construction from non-temporary rvalue*/}
```

Currently, I check an undesired constructor DOES NOT compile, but then of course I have to comment it out to get the tests to compile again!

If I could do:

```
static_assert(DOES_NOT_COMPILE(myclass_t("Hello")));

const char* help = "HELP";
static_assert(!DOES_NOT_COMPILE(myclass_t(help))); 
// COMPILES() might be better here :-)
```

That would help me a great deal, but I cannot seem to find a general SFINAE solution. C++14 only, so:

```
if constexpr
```

is not available.

Comment: Your questions is anything but clear. I presume what you want is to `static_assert` that a certain construct *would be* illegal.

Comment: No, I want to be able to assert that something definitely *would not* compile, whilst having a working program ! To be clear: I want to test that I don't leave any holes in my type system!

Comment: Ahem, I think this is *exactly* what I have presumed. So why do you start with *No*... ? Actually, if properly formulated, this could be a good question. (btw, I'm *not* the downvoter)

Comment: By the way, your first code is wrong.

Comment: @Yakk Can you post somewhere a blurb with how to do it in C++17? I'm more than curious.

Comment: @liliscent "your first code" is not helpful. Not only do I not know what part of the code you are talking about, the comment is not helpful unless it both calls out what is incorrect, why, and how to make it correct.

Comment: I'm trying to fill in the blanks in your question, and it's difficult.  Would you be willing to replace your "I believe the pattern is" pseudocode with an actual small class that compiles, and show actual usage of it that compiles, and a second usage of it that fails to compile (as desired)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following macro lets you rewrite a SFINAE-unfriendly expression such as `[](auto&&x) { return x+1; }` in a SFINAE-friendly way.

```
#define RETURNS(...)\
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__))\
  ->decltype(__VA_ARGS__)\
  { return __VA_ARGS__;}
```

So that lets you rewrite the above lambda expression like this:

```
[](auto&&x) RETURNS( x+1 )
```

or, another example:

```
struct { template<class X> auto operator()(X&&x) RETURNS(x+1) };
```

and it is SFINAE friendly.  `RETURNS` isn't actually required, but it makes much of the code so much cleaner.  There is a [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) proposal to replace `RETURNS` with `=>` by SO's own @barry.

Next we need to be able to test if a function object can be called.

```
namespace details {
  template<class, class, class...>
  struct can_invoke:std::false_type{};
  template<class F, class...Args>
  struct can_invoke<
    F,
    std::void_t<std::result_of_t<F&&(Args&&...)>>,
    Args...
  >:
    std::true_type
  {};
}
template<class F, class...Args>
using can_invoke=details::can_invoke<F,void,Args...>;
```

we are almost there.  (This is the core of the technique; I sometimes use `can_apply` that takes `template<class...>class Z` instead of `class F` here.)  [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) has a similar trait; it can be used instead.

`test_invoke` takes callable and returns a callable tester.  A callable tester takes arguments, and returns true or false types based on "could the original callable be called with these arguments".

```
template<class F>
constexpr auto test_invoke(F&&){
  return [](auto&&...args) RETURNS( can_invoke< F, decltype(args)... >{} );
}
```

and here we are.  `test_invoke` can be skipped if you are willing to work with pure types, but working with values can eliminate some bugs.

```
auto myclass_ctor=[](auto&&...args)RETURNS(myclass_t(decltype(args)(args)...));
```

`myclass_ctor` is a callable object that represents constructing `myclass_t`.

```
static_assert(!test_invoke(myclass_ctor)("Hello") );
```

or

```
template<class C>
auto ctor=[](auto&&...args)RETURNS(C(decltype(args)(args)...));
static_assert(!test_invoke(ctor<myclass_t>)("Hello") );
```

this requires constexpr lambda, a [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) feature but an early one.  It can be done without it but it gets ugly.  Plus move ctor requirement of elision is annoying to work around in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14).

To translate to [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), replace every lambda with a manual function object with appropriate constexpr special member functions.  `RETURNS` applies to `operator()` just as well, as demonstrated above.

To get around elision move ctor requrement, `RETURNS(void( blah ))`.

Apologies for any tyops; I am on phone.

Comment: Bloody hell, the patience.

Comment: @Quentin Hmm?  I don't understand.

Comment: Thank you @Yakk, this is gold. I've expanded on your pattern in a separate answer. Feel free to comment or Incorporate from it what if you want. Also, what would C++17 simplify?

Comment: @johan this answer as written is 17; lambdas are only constexpr there.  Translating to 14 is just verbose and boring and mechanical as we have to write "manual lambdas".

Comment: @Yakk to write all of this answer on a phone, I mean.

Comment: Which compilers and compiler versions are capable  of handling this? I tried it on godbolt and saw a mix of compile errors and internal compiler errors using recent versions of major compilers.

Answer (score 4):

Building on @Yakk's answer, which I find amazing. We can never hope to

```
static_assert(!DOES_NOT_COMPILE(myclass_t(help)));
```

because there must be a type dependency to delay the error, and that's what Yakk is doing. Using another macro, together with default lambda capture:

```
STATIC_ASSERT_NOT_COMPILES(myclass_t(MK_DEP(help)));
```

`MAKE_DEP` is a templated function object, which is injected by the macro to provide the required dependency. Example use:

```
void foo(){

    std::string s;
    const std::string cs; 

    STATIC_ASSERT_NOT_COMPILES(cs=MK_DEP(s));
    STATIC_ASSERT_NOT_COMPILES(MK_DEP(cs).clear());
    // This fires, because s can be cleared:
    //STATIC_ASSERT_NOT_COMPILES(MK_DEP(s).clear()); // Fails to compile, OK!

    class C{}; // just an example class
    C c;
    STATIC_ASSERT_NOT_COMPILES(c=MK_DEP(7));
    STATIC_ASSERT_NOT_COMPILES(7=MK_DEP(c));
    STATIC_ASSERT_NOT_COMPILES(baz(foo(MK_DEP(7)=c)));
    STATIC_ASSERT_NOT_COMPILES(MK_DEP(false)=1);

    // What about constructing C from string?
    STATIC_ASSERT_NOT_COMPILES(C(MK_DEP(std::string{})));

    // assert fires: can add strings: OK!
    //STATIC_ASSERT_NOT_COMPILES(MK_DEP(s)+cs+std::string());

    // Too many arguments to MK_DEP is forced to give hard error: Fails to compile, OK!
    // STATIC_ASSERT_NOT_COMPILES(MK_DEP(1,2,3)+1);

    // Forgetting to add MK_DEP also gives a *hard* error. Fails to compile. OK!
    // STATIC_ASSERT_NOT_COMPILES(7=c);
}
```

Implementation, relying on Yakk's `test_invoke` and `RETURNS`. Feedback welcome!

```
namespace details{    
    struct make_depend{
        template<typename T> static constexpr const bool false_t = false;
        template<typename T>
        auto operator()(T&& arg) RETURNS(arg) ;
        // Try to protect against wrong use: zero or many arguments:
        template<typename T, typename... T2>
        auto operator()(T&& arg, T2... too_many_arguments) { 
            static_assert(false_t<T>, "Too many arguments given to MK_DEP"); } ;
        template<typename T=int>
        auto operator()()  { static_assert(false_t<T>, "Too few arguments given to MK_DEP"); } ;
    };
}

#define STATIC_ASSERT_NOT_COMPILES(...)\
    static_assert(!test_invoke([&](auto MK_DEP)RETURNS(__VA_ARGS__))\
       (details::make_depend{}))
```

Alternatively, a somewhat less wrapped approach:

```
#define CHECK_COMPILES(...)\
    test_invoke([&](auto MK_DEP)RETURNS(__VA_ARGS__))(details::make_depend{})

static_assert(CHECK_COMPILES(cs=MK_DEP(s)));
```

Or even just the basic idea:

```
static_assert(test_invoke([&](auto MK_DEP)RETURNS(s+MK_DEP(s)))(details::make_depend{}));
```

[Compiler explorer demo](https://godbolt.org/g/RXAWTZ)

**EDIT:** The variadic `operator()` is just to protect against some cases of wrong use of `MK_DEP`. I also added a no-argument version for the same reason.

Comment: Why varardic operator () in make depends?

Comment: Also note there are some gotchas.  For example, if you are testing "can I construct Foo from Bar" and Foo has no valid 1 arg ctors, `Foo(MK_DEP(Bar{}))` makes your program ill formed, no diagnostic required as there isn't any possible valid instantiations of the lambda wrapping it...  Which is one of the reasons I don't think we can safely "hide the magic" behind macros.  This trick is at the edge of what C++ permits.

Comment: @Yakk, the variadic operator(), and a no-argument one I just added, is just to protect against some bad usages. I don't follow you other comment, but I'm a afraid this comment field will not be enough. 
If you have the time I would be very thankful if you could contact me on slack or mail.

Comment: all template functions must have a possible instantiation or your program is ill formed, no diagnostic required.   I am concerned your techniques hide this behind magic.  Suppose `Foo` has no 2 arg ctors; then `Foo(MK_DEP(a), MK_DEP(b))` in a template function makes your program ill formed, even if your current compiler is fooled by the `MK_DEP`.  Your macros hide what is happening, and that can hide things that make programs ill formed.

Comment: @Yakk, I agree. Thank you. Just as `myclass_ctor` is ill formed ndr if there is no single argument constructor, but there it's at least clear (!) that it's the fault of the designer of `myclass_ctor`. I think that  `7=MK_DEP(c)` is also not legal, unless I add something to the machinery to allow that statement for *some* type of `c`.

Comment: Which compilers, compiler versions and compile settings are needed for this? I tried the compiler explorer demo and saw a mix of compile errors and internal compiler errors using recent versions of major compilers.

Comment: Looks like this works only in clang, but not in GCC. But why?

Comment: UPDATE: 06/10/21: Compiles in Compiler Explorer in GCC and Clang, but does not seem to work in MSVC latest